# Getting abnormally high negative temperature even though rtd is at room temperature using adafruit_max31865

Tags: adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I am trying to log temperature using MAX31865 module and Raspberry Pi.
I have written following python code:

```
import board
import busio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction
import adafruit_max31865
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCLK(), MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
cs = DigitalInOut(board.D11)  # Chip select of the MAX31865 board.
rtd = adafruit_max31865.MAX31865(spi, cs)
```

Above code is giving rtd.temperature value equal to -242.02
What could be the problem?

I have checked the all pin connections. RTD sensor is also working fine.

Comment: You could try setting the number of wires, RTD and reference resistor as suggested in the docs: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max31865-rtd-pt100-amplifier/python-circuitpython

Comment: This question would be a better fit for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/